# How can one replicate Django admins add new row functionality?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-1.8, django-admin-actions

I am looking for a way to implement the "add new model_name" functionality from Django admin to normal form in templates, i.e; outside of Django admin, how could I use the same functionality.

[image]

How could I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

The first Step is to create Business Module inside models.py

```
class Business(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ('name',)
            verbose_name = 'business'
            verbose_name_plural = 'business'

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

Then use `python manage.py migrate` to migrate module inside your database.

Now open admin.py file and register this Module,

```
from .models import Business

# Register your models here.
class BusinessAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'slug']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}
admin.site.register(Business,BusinessAdmin)
```

Now check your Django admin panel. It will show you New Business Module there with Add, remove feature using Form.

I hope this will helpful for you.

Comment: I think I have not made it clear in the description. I am sorry, but I am looking for a way to replicate it outside of Django admin in normal templates  which is used to fill the form and not inside Django admin.